How to type function to ensure keys of two properties have the same property type
I have the following typescript function (simplified for this question):
function assign<T1,T2>(o1:T1,k1:keyof T1, o2:T2, k2:keyof T2){
    o1[k1] = o2[k2];
}

I want to ensure that the data type of o1[k1] is the same as that of o2[k2]. Meaning that the function will only allow combinations of property names where assignments of the values will be possible. Example:
let a = {foo: 'hello', version: 10};
let b = {bar: 'bye'};
assign(a, 'foo',b, 'bar'); // This should be allowed as both properties are strings
assign(a, 'version',b, 'bar'); // This should give a type error as the properties have different types

I tried using mapped types etc. but was not able to find a correctly working solution.
For example:
function assign<T1,T2>(o1:T1,k1:keyof T1, o2:T2,
           k2:T1[K1] extends T2[K2]?keyof T2:never){
    o1[k1] = o2[k2];
}


But that does not work. Any ideas?

You can try typing second object based on values from first object:
function assign<Obj1 extends {}, Key1 extends keyof Obj1, Key2 extends string>(o1: Obj1, k1: Key1, o2: {[k in Key2]: Obj1[Key1]}, k2: Key2) {
    o1[k1] = o2[k2];
}

let a = {foo: 'hello', version: 10};
let b = {bar: 'bye'};
assign(a, 'foo', b, 'bar'); // Ok
assign(a, 'version', b, 'bar'); // Error: Argument of type '{ bar: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ bar: number; }'.


Thanks, this works. But it seems type completion is not able to propose the valid key values for parameter k2. Any suggestions?

You'll first need to infer the exact key types of both parameters using generics. Then you can simply compare its value types using T2[K2] extends T1[K1] ? K2 : never. If the second key's value is assignable to the first one everything is fine. Otherwise we use never in order to throw a compiler error.
declare function assign<T1, K1 extends keyof T1, T2, K2 extends keyof T2>(
  o1: T1,
  k1: K1,
  o2: T2,
  k2: T2[K2] extends T1[K1] ? K2 : never,
): unknown;

let a = { foo: "hello", version: 10 };
let b = { bar: "bye" };
assign(a, "foo", b, "bar");
assign(a, "version", b, "bar");
//                      ~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

TypeScript Playground

This does not seem to work:
function assign<T1, K1 extends keyof T1, T2, K2 extends keyof T2>(
o1: T1,
k1: K1,
o2: T2,
//k2: { [K in keyof T2]: T2[K] extends T1[K1] ? K : never }[keyof T2]
k2: T2[K2] extends T1[K1] ? K2 : never
){
o1[k1] = o2[k2];
}
It gives an error for o1[k1]

The assignment is an issue for itself and I believe, unfortunately, there's not one correct straight forward answer. You might want to check out this other post.
